# Sci-fi movie with weather control and girl with coloured hair

Tags: story-identification, movie

So I'm trying to remember the name of a movie that I watched back maybe 10 years ago or more. The major details I remember about this film are

1. The girl in the film had different coloured hair
2. There was weather control as a plot point  .
3. I believe the main protagonist was really good at using computers.
4. The primary antagonists seemed to be a government agency and eventually threaten the protagonists mother.
5. I believe the film was poorly received.
6. It was live-action.
7. The main character was a young adult as was the female he eventually met.

I don't know if I just hallucinated this movie but I swear it exists and it's not just me merging multiple movies into one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Was this a live-action movie or animated?  Please check out the [other suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit] in any more details you recall.

Comment: Apologies, I shall add what I can. It was live-action.

Comment: I am petty sure my box of 64 crayons has exactly *none* that are labeled "different color." Can you edit your question to be more detailed? :)  Also: welcome to SFF!

Comment: Maybe it is "scott pilgrim vs the world" it matches 1, 2 and 7

Comment: By "different coloured hair", do you mean some of her hair was one colour and some was another?  (I think this is an English problem - the native speakers like me are interpreting it as meaning "hair of a single colour that is different to..." and then puzzling over what it is different to.

Comment: @Criticalimpact  I also want to know if you mean hair that has two or more different colors, or hair of one color which is different from that of other characters, or hair that is different from real world hair colors. Note that where I come from native English speakers write "different from" instead of "different to".

Comment: [The Avengers (1998 movie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%281998_film%29) matches points 1 (Uma Thurman has a different color hair, somehow), 2 (Sir August de Wynter's plan is about weather control), 4 (they work for an agency and somebody threatens "Mother" at some point, altough it is a man), 5 (yes), and 6. Can't remember about point 3 and point 7 is debatable as the characters were in their 30s at the time.

Comment: I am fairly certain that the hair was a solid colour. It had been dyed blue, green or some other fairly striking colour and was not a streak of colour or mix of 2 colours.   
It was not The Avengers though I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more searching I found the movie and maybe it should have stayed buried in the deepest recesses of my mind but in case anyone was wondering the movie was called "[Storm Watch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311866/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)" or it also went by the name "Code Hunter"

> America's best player is being pulled in to the ultimate cyber-terror. The game's mastermind has stolen his identity, put him on the FBI's Most Wanted List, and is blackmailing him to take a part in a real twisted plan of world destruction. With just hours left, can the code be broken to save the world from total annihilation?

The summary from [the film's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Watch) mentions the weather control:

> torm Watch is a 2002 American science fiction film, directed by Terry Cunningham and starring Adrian Paul and Bai Ling. The music was composed by Sean Murray. The film centers on a protagonist who plays a virtual reality online game, which suddenly turns into a race against time to stop a weather satellite from destroying the world. The film was released on DVD and VHS under the title *Code Hunter*.

### Trailer

Comment: You will be able to accept your own answer in about 31 hours, and we ask that you please do so.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it was a movie, and not a series?  Because it sounds like the episode of Gene Rodeenberry's Andromeda, where Beka Valentine reveals that she can change her hair color, and where she complains about how she "hates weather".

Comment: I'm afraid it was definitely a movie. I had a DVD of it and it was definitely a feature length film.